# What is the concept & idea behind AssetFileDescriptor in Android API

Tags: android

What is the concept & idea behind AssetFileDescriptor in Android API? I have referred:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor.html but it didn't help me Understand the Concept and idea behind using it. Since I am new to Android API and having difficulty in understanding many of its concepts please be as slang as possible.

Comment: Same as for any other `FileDescriptor`, just specifically for assets. You can get a normal `FileDescriptor` by calling `getFileDescriptor()`.